# Being innovative (in Web Design/Development) while maintaining backward-compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

I love building websites, and I love making them compatible with as many different platforms, devices and browsers as possible, but I am really getting sick of it nowadays to be honest.

I am sick of not being able to implement my best ideas because the technology so many people refuse to give up is not up to the task. I am talking about IE 6, 7 and 8 - and older versions of other browsers - and people not enabling JavaScript.

I understand the many different reasons for not updating and also for disabling JS - but I still need to get things done and I **don't** want to miss out on potential sales just because these people refuse to update their browsers or enable JS.

So, now I am thinking, maybe there's a way around it that I'm not aware of. Could I be doing things differently? Is there a way to accommodate these users and be [as] innovative [as I want to be]?

Comment: What is your specific question? The specific problem?

Comment: Screen resolution and size. Stack Overflow looks great, but on my new monitor (23) inch - it looks like it was made for a 15 inch monitor. (no offense intended, just an example I'm using) - JavaScript - so many things are necessary these days if you want your site to stand out and if you _really_ want to give them the best, you really need javascript. And I know I can just "fall back" for "the others", but that's what I'm sick of. I don't want some people to have a "lesser" experience - I want the experience to be the same for everyone.

Comment: This is not a technology problem, but rather a people problem. You  need to convince people not to use IE6 (etc) by not developing solutions for or supporting that platform - EG: http://www.ie6nomore.com/. If that is not acceptable you either need to find new clients or deal with these older browsers.

Comment: @JustinEthier I agree 100% with you with regards to not updating the browsers. And I'm more than prepared to go ahead without them, but it's the ones who aren't allowed to, or don't want to enable Scripting in their browsers (most likely for security reasons) - it's those ones who are stopping me from just going all out and saying "if you don't like it - screw you. Update or stay away.)

Comment: You ask a fundamental question to what no wrong or right answers are existing. Only personal meanings. You ask in the wrong place. This forum is for specific coding problems.

Comment: This is a business problem. You can install Google Analytics tools to get an exact number of who is using IE6,7,8. The number might be less than 1%, who knows? This will at least allow you to run a cost benefit analysis to see if it's even worth your time to support older browser.

Comment: Install G Analytics? I always thought it was a Web Service (the browser-type). Thanks for the tip, I'm going to sign up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only so much you can do. I try to be as compatible for websites within reason, but once I hit the point where I have to sacrifice functionality just to let people who won't update their browsers use the site I decide it is not my problem at that point. It is not my responsibility to keep stuff working for your 10 year old browser (not to mention the huge amount of security risks with using tech that old).

Comment: I think you just convinced me. People disable JavaScript mainly due to security reasons (correct me if I'm wrong) - yet they still refuse to update their browsers (which -can be- is a security risk). So _they_ don't win either way. I think I'll just do what I want from now on. I'll support the technology that supports me. (and Thanks :)